# Grails GSP pages not pre-compiled?

Tags: grails, gsp

We are running our grails probject with `run-app`. The first time a page is requested, there is a delay. Every time after that, however, the page loads quickly.

The most obvious explanation I can think of is that the page hasn't been compiled yet. Is there a way to induce compilation or whatever else is causing the delay?

Comment: We also see the same delay when deploying to a standalone Tomcat as a WAR file. The delay seems shorter than when in development mode and a GSP has been changed but definitely longer than after the first access. I guess I could connect YourKit and see what's it's doing during that time.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you are only using "`run-app`" in development and not in production.

If you want to pre-compile the GSPs then use "`run-war`".

Be aware though, changes to the GSP will not be detected and you will have to restart the application or make changes to your configuration to enable dynamic recompile.

To enable dynamic recompile of GSPs when running as a WAR modify your `Config.groovy` with the following:

```
grails.gsp.enable.reload = true 
grails.gsp.view.dir = "/path/to/WEB-INF/"
```

I can't stress enough, if this isn't in development, and instead is production, deploy your application as a WAR file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Haven't tried with run-war yet, but I imagine it will work.